# JavaScript form validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a very simple form with a very simple JavaScript validator.

I want an alert to popup if the first nae isnt filled out only it doesnt seem to be alerting and still submits.

I've uploaded a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nvgMq/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do client form validation from scratch? Advise: Don't. Use JQuery validation or .NET's built in.

Comment: There is no point why he should not make his own form validation is there? I think it's a good practice.

Comment: I he's building it with asp.net, the sensible thing to do is use the asp.net validators. He shouldn't be reinventing the wheel when he has a good wheel in his posession.

Answer (score 1):

You code is correct but it's jsfiddle's problem. After inspecting the jsfiddle's HTML page, I found out that the JavaScript code has become:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    function validateForm()
     {
       var x=document.forms["subForm"]["ajijjt-ajijjt"].value

        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
      }
});
```

So the function `validateForm` is no longer a global variable, it can not be accessed in the `<form>`'s `onsubmit`.

You can use code like:

```
window.validateForm = function() {}
```

This will create the global variable for `validateForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of x?  Try putting a semi colon after the .value

var x=document.forms["subForm"]["ajijjt-ajijjt"].value;